# How to access methods and properties on an HTML element obtained from the response of Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: html, powershell, dom

I have a table element of my_table class. However, I seem to be unable to access any of its methods or properties.

Please, observe:

```
C:\Work> $table = $res.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('my_table')
C:\Work> $table | Get-Member | sls className

IHTMLElementCollection getElementsByClassName (string)
string className () {get} {set}

C:\Work> $table.className
C:\Work> $table | Get-Member | sls getAttribute

Variant getAttribute (string, int)
IHTMLDOMAttribute getAttributeNode (string)
IHTMLDOMAttribute2 getAttributeNodeNS (Variant, string)
Variant getAttributeNS (Variant, string)
Variant ie8_getAttribute (string)
IHTMLDOMAttribute2 ie8_getAttributeNode (string)
Variant ie9_getAttribute (string)
IHTMLDOMAttribute2 ie9_getAttributeNode (string)

C:\Work> $table.getAttributeNode('className')
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'getAttributeNode'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $table.getAttributeNode('className')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getAttributeNode:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

C:\Work>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Item()` like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497711/method-invocation-failed-because-system-comobject-does-not-co-ntain-a-method) ?

Comment: Actually it does work. So, my question is a duplicate. But why does it work? (voting to close as a duplicate)

Comment: `__ComObject` is a wrapper for an object that exposes some additional COM methods and properties to Powershell. I'm not sure about the design choice to add the `Item()` method that exposes the actual object, but I'd guess it's to prevent any method or property name duplication with the COM wrapper. It would be very confusing if  `__ComObject` also exposed a method `getAttribute()`, right?

Comment: Is there a documentation anywhere about it?

Comment: There's [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__comobject.cs) that looks interesting, but I haven't found any specific documentation about how Item() maps to the original object.